# Force video size in HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, embed

I'm trying to build a very simple proof-of-concept for the guys I work for to demonstrate something for them. As of right now, I've got everything working, except that in my (obviously extremely crude) website, I'm trying to embed a video and FORCE the video to completely fill a certain size. The main problem that I'm facing is that if I try to embed a video with:

```
<video width="1920" height="1080">
```

then it increases the size of the video screen (though not to those actual dimensions - it stops at a much smaller size), but keeps the actual viewable video size at the original dimensions and just adds a lot of black space into the video player.

Clearly, this isn't the right way to do this. I know HTML is usually regarded as pretty easy, but this is literally the first webpage I've had to do, haha. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the source of your video?

Comment: The video is stored in a folder with the actual .html file itself. It's an .avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this @ http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_video_height.asp

*Note: Do not rescale video with the height and width attributes! Downsizing a large video with the height and width attributes forces a user to download the original video (even if it looks small on the page). The correct way to rescale a video is with a program, before using it on a page.*

So guess you can't scale up a video with width and height tags. Just define it's dimensions so the browser can reserve space for it while loading a webpage.

Comment: Correct: "If you specify a size smaller than the source, the entire video will scale down. However, if you specify a size larger than the source, the video will display in its original size, with the remainder of the dimensions you specified filled by empty space." www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/how-to-embed-video-using-html5.html